# How to remove cross browser effect in css

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

How to remove cross browser effect in css using javascript or jquery or php
or any script for remove all cross browser effects in css

ex:

```
-moz-transform: matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0); 
    -o-transform: matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform : matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform : matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0);
```

i need that if i write css as  `-moz-transform:matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0);` it should apply for any browser, nothin change in chrome IE or safari or etc

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `any browser`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `JS` plugin for this http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ may be that's help you

Comment: it is not working, any example that u know about it 
thank you

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more about how it is not working. And if you think you've found a bug, you may want to post about it here: https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/issues

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to write this line one time, you should write it like this:

```
transform: matrix(0.99998, -0.00638621, 0.00638621, 0.99998, 0, 0);
```

And then wait until transform is part of the official standard and all browsers recognize it. Until then, maybe http://prefixr.com/ will help you. There is a reason that the prefix is still required. Please understand that reason.

Comment: prefixr.com is not a script, it is a website. You can use it as such or you can use their api to integrate their features with your code editor. There are plugins and things here: http://www.prefixr.com/api/usage/

Comment: i need a script for that, if u know any script plz inform me thank you